# How to keep shutter speed and aperture when changing modes on Canon 7D?

Tags: camera-settings, canon-7d

Shutter speed and aperture are not kept when changing between manual, aperture priority (Av) and shutter priority (Tv). That is, if I

1. set aperture to F8 in aperture priority,
2. change to manual mode,
3. set aperture to F1.2 and
4. change back to aperture priority

the aperture is now F8. Is there some setting to make sure the settings are instead carried over, just as they are for ISO, white balance and others?

Comment: They aren't (well, it shouldn't be) for ISO OR WB. Set WB and ISO on Manual mode and see if it's kept when you change it to Av ot Tv. BTW, why would you want to do this? Why not use use Av and select apertures you want that way?

Comment: A change in ISO carries over when changing back to modes that were last used with a different ISO on my Canon cameras (with the exception of the C1, C2, C3 modes). I shoot raw and rarely change the WB setting from "Auto" so I haven't really noticed if it carries over or not.

Comment: I specifically asked about shutter speed and aperture because those are as far as I can tell the *only* settings which are not carried over between modes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

P, Tv, Av, M, Bulb and (in our discussion) the Custom modes (C1, C2, C3 etc.) have all **different/independent values for Av and Tv stored in separate memory locations** in camera's NVRAM for the user-definable (constant) part of the said program (none for P, Time for Tv, Aperture for Av, both for M etc.).

Comment: By and large most photographers prefer that the camera "remembers" the settings from the last time they were in a particular mode. It makes it very useful when shooting in a context that requires very different settings for shooting in different directions or at different focal lengths. You just move the mode dial and you're right back where you were before you left that mode!

Comment: @MichaelClark But shutter speed and aperture seem to be the only two settings which are *not* carried over between modes - ISO, white balance and others are copied, so why not specifically these two?

Comment: @l0b0: Because, at least historically speaking, **these are the two things which affect the *photograph* in a much greater degree than all other factors while being the most dynamic parameters**. This was especially true in the film days when the 'ISO' was "fixed" (you had a roll of film of a certain ISO) and, also, in the modern days when ISO is set to 'Auto' for a wide range of situations, hence the ISO 'disappears' from photog's attention.
You can think at all other settings like a more or less stable 'frame' of settings in which you play with Aperture and Time.

Comment: @l0b0: ...Also, your question was HOW TO KEEP Av/TV and not WHY THESE AREN'T KEPT. IMHO, while I tried to answer you in my comment above, spanning (sub)questions in comments section isn't a good practice.